# Python subprocess module doesn't work after bundling my code with Pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, subprocess, pyqt6

I wrote a simple function that just runs ffmpeg with subprocess.Popen as following.

```
def convert(path_input, path_output):
    subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg", "-i", path_input, path_output], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

And a tiple PyQt6 gui for triggering this function. When i test my code it runs properly. But after bundling with Pyinstaller, the app (gui) itself runs but when i press the button to trigger the function it fails.

I also tried as following.

```
def convert(path_input, path_output):
    subprocess.Popen([f"ffmpeg -i {path_input} {path_output}"], shell=True,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

But this time it doesn't throw any error but it does nothing. This problem occurs when i use macOS bundled app which I simply created by this command.

`$pyinstaller --windowed ffmpeg_gui.py`

I tried so many things but it seems the problem subprocess itself. So if anyone helps me, I appreciate.

My full code as following.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import os
import subprocess

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QWidget,
    QPushButton,
    QLabel,
    QFileDialog,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QDialog
)

from PyQt6.QtCore import (
    QSize
)


def convert(path_input, path_output):
    subprocess.Popen([f"ffmpeg -i {path_input} {path_output}"], shell=True,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(500, 400))

        self.label_input = QLabel("Select The Video For Converting")
        self.label_output = QLabel("Select The Folder For Converted File")

        self.button_input = QPushButton("Select File")
        self.button_output = QPushButton("Select Folder")
        self.button_start = QPushButton("Start")

        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout_top = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout_middle = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout_buttom = QHBoxLayout()

        self.layout_top.addWidget(self.label_input)
        self.layout_top.addWidget(self.button_input)

        self.layout_middle.addWidget(self.label_output)
        self.layout_middle.addWidget(self.button_output)

        self.layout_buttom.addWidget(self.button_start)

        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.layout_top)
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.layout_middle)
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.layout_buttom)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.button_input.clicked.connect(self.select_file)
        self.button_start.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.button_output.clicked.connect(self.select_folder)

    def select_file(self):
        file_path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        self.file_path = file_path
        return 0

    def select_folder(self):
        folder_path = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
            self, "Select a Folder")
        self.folder_path = folder_path
        self.output_path = os.path.join(folder_path, "output.mp3")
        return 0

    def start(self):
        if hasattr(self, "file_path") and hasattr(self, "folder_path"):
            if not os.path.isfile(self.output_path):
                convert(self.file_path, self.output_path)

                dlg = QDialog(self)
                dlg.setWindowTitle("DONE")
                dlg.setFixedSize(QSize(400, 100))
                message = QLabel(dlg)
                message.setText("Conversion is succesfully finished!")
                dlg.setStyleSheet(
                    "QLabel{font-size: 20pt; margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 25px}")
                dlg.exec()
            else:
                dlg = QDialog(self)
                dlg.setWindowTitle("ERROR")
                dlg.setFixedSize(QSize(400, 100))
                message = QLabel(dlg)
                message.setText("Already a file exists!")
                dlg.setStyleSheet(
                    "QLabel{font-size: 20pt; margin-left: 90px; margin-top: 25px}")
                dlg.exec()
        else:
            dlg = QDialog(self)
            dlg.setWindowTitle("ERROR")
            dlg.setFixedSize(QSize(400, 100))
            message = QLabel(dlg)
            message.setText("No File or Folder Selected!")
            dlg.setStyleSheet(
                "QLabel{font-size: 20pt; margin-left: 90px; margin-top: 25px}")
            dlg.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: Is ffmpeg installed on the target machine or did you include it in your package?

Comment: ffmpeg is installed and runs flawlessly. I did't include any library for subprocess. It didn't work. But then I tried to include ffmpeg executable with Pyinstaller by addin "--add-data" and it worked. Thank for your interest.

Comment: Note that, since you're on a unix like system, including the executable alone might not be sufficient, and might even completely fail at all: ffmpeg is quite a complex program that often has optimized compilation flags that only work fine on certain specific architectures for which it has been built against, and it's usually installed not as a standalone file, but using linked libraries that will obviously not exist on a possible target machine. Long story short, if you want to distribute a package that relies on ffmpeg, you need *at least* to add its full package (or a way to install it).

Comment: I am a rookie and writing code and learning programming for myself. Thank you very much for your answers. They helped a lot.